# Clear bootstrap datapicker value from input-group-addon span element?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using `bootstrap-datapicker` for selecting a date. The `textfield` for the date is readonly so I have to create two buttons, one is for selecting the date and the other one is to clear it. Here is the code in aspx page

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker2'>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxSecondDate" runat="server" CssClass="form-control input-md remove-glow" placeholder="Deri:"></asp:TextBox>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>
        </span>
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="fa fa-times clear-date" id="SecondDate"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

The problem is when i try to add an event to clear-date span it doesn`t clear the date but it opens by default the calendar. Any idea how can i solve the problem ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you update snippet with datepicker library you are using and also javascript code you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/moment.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false,
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            ignoreReadonly: true
        });
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false,
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
            ignoreReadonly: true
        });
        $("#datetimepicker1").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
            $("#datetimepicker1").datepicker('hide');
        });
        $("#datetimepicker2").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker1').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
            $("#datetimepicker2").datepicker('hide');
        });

    });
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("body").on('click', ".clear-date", function () {
            $('#datetimepicker2').data("DateTimePicker").clear();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my code in javascript.